# Trigger of mysql with server ip address and username

Tags: mysql

I want to monitor who is doing update, insert, delete entries in mysql server with IP username,
I got below answers but its not showing me IP instead it shows local hots.

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';

select * from general_log;
```

Comment: Those will be the IPs of the user in `mysql.user`. So the `host` for user is `localhost`, right?

Comment: for instance ,if 'm connected from a client and do changed in mysql server, how can i trace logs for the same?